# ScrollTop has hesitation when returning to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to change css styles as a user scrolls down and set them back to how they were when the user scrolls back to the top.

```
$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#mainMenu').animate({marginTop: '15px'},300);
        $('#phoneNumber').animate({opacity: '0'},300);
        $('#mainNav').addClass("mainNavScroll");
    } else {
        $('#mainMenu').animate({marginTop: '70px'},300);
        $('#phoneNumber').animate({opacity: '1'},300);
        $('#mainNav').removeClass("mainNavScroll");
    }
});
```

It does the top part of the code (the first "if" section) fine but when I scroll back up to the top, I have problems with the "else" code. It does the last line right away (removes `.mainNavScroll` from `#mainNav`) and then waits about a minute to do the rest of the code (animations for `#mainMenu` and `#phoneNumber`).

Comment: You have to use `stop()` on the every animate first, since the scroll event is triggered an enormous amount of times, therefore chocking your system. Try `$(something).stop().animate();` You are dealing with a _Stack Overflow_ (As Peter Griffin would say: 'Thats why they call it that')

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
var top = true;
$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if (top) {
            top = false;
            $('#mainMenu').stop().animate({marginTop: '15px'},300);
            $('#phoneNumber').stop().animate({opacity: '0'},300);
            $('#mainNav').stop().addClass("mainNavScroll");
        }
    } else if (!top) {
        top = true;
        $('#mainMenu').animate({marginTop: '70px'},300);
        $('#phoneNumber').animate({opacity: '1'},300);
        $('#mainNav').removeClass("mainNavScroll");
    }
});
```

The `.stop()`'s will stop any animation that is currently running before running the next. This will prevent queues where animations wait for each other.

The `top` var is to prevent the non-top animations from being triggered thousands of times while scrolling.

If you want the class added/removed after the animations are complete, you can use a callback like this:

```
$('#mainMenu').animate({marginTop: '70px'},300, function() {
    $('#mainNav').removeClass("mainNavScroll");
});
```